# Making a list of pairwise comparisons between specific groups of data

Tags: r, list, comparison, pairwise, combn

I have two dfs that look something like this:

```
dat2 <- read.table(text = "
 year  nodepair  `++`  `--`  `+-`  `-+`  `0+`  `+0`  `0-`  `-0`  `00` ES   
1 1999  A1_A1        0     4     0     0     0     0     0     0    16 3    
2 1999  A2_A1        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    20 3    
3 1999  A2_A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    20 4    
4 1999  A3_A1        0     0     0     0     0     2     0     0    18 4    
5 1999  A3_A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    20 5    
6 1999  A3_A3        0     5     0     0     0     0     0     0    15 5    
", header = TRUE)
```

```
dat3 <- read.table(text = "
 year  nodepair  `++`  `--`  `+-`  `-+`  `0+`  `+0`  `0-`  `-0`  `00` ES   
1 1999  A1_A1        0     4     0     0     0     0     0     0    16 8    
2 1999  A2_A1        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    20 8    
3 1999  A2_A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    20 9    
4 1999  A3_A1        0     0     0     0     0     2     0     0    18 9    
5 1999  A3_A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    20 10    
6 1999  A3_A3        0     5     0     0     0     0     0     0    15 10    
", header = TRUE)
```

I'm writing a code that uses pairwise lists to compare between the ES groups.  Before I was able to successfully put these together and make a pairwise list of ALL combinations using:

```
dat4 <- rbind(dat2,dat3)
ES_combs <- combn(unique(dat4$ES), 2, simplify = FALSE)
```

but this time I need to make a pairwise list between these two different groups of ESs to make my new function.  so 3-8, 3-9, 3-10, 4-8... etc and not within the set (not 3-4, 4-5).

Comment: Is this `expand.grid(unique(dat2$ES), unique(dat3$ES))`?

Comment: Extending @CPB's suggestion: `x = expand.grid(unique(dat2$ES), unique(dat3$ES)); x = x[order(x$Var1), ]; paste0(x$Var1, "-", x$Var2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```r
> x = expand.grid(unique(dat2$ES), unique(dat3$ES))
> x = x[order(x$Var1), ]
> paste0(x$Var1, "-", x$Var2)
[1] "3-8"  "3-9"  "3-10" "4-8"  "4-9"  "4-10" "5-8"  "5-9"  "5-10"
```

which is an extension of @CPB's comment.

Comment: Awesome @CPB and @Friede. I just needed to add: `Tlist <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) ## to make it a list object`